# I'm trying to find out if this image is AI or not. What are some indications it is or isn't?

Tags: images, designers, image-quality, midjourney, artificial-intelligence

[image]

Image in question

I am working on a book, and I've considered using AI art as I've used it a lot for my D&D campaign to display certain aspects, though I decided to use a real artist, but now I am unsure that I'm looking at real art. I have reason to believe it isn't AI, as the person I've commissioned seems legit, but then the art I've received versus the art on his profile, doesn't seem to match at all. What's more, the prompt I gave and what I received, also doesn't match at all. I am working on a project, which I could easily finish with AI, but as I want to support artists, I've decided to work with artists however, I can't be sure that this wasn't AI as I can see some flaws that look suspicious.

Comment: At least the maker of the composition knows nothing of perspective. See, how the vertical lines point to different directions. That happens easily when one tries to put together several 2D images. In a well constructed image they should point to the same vanishing point or use a simplification where all of them are vertical.

Comment: Generally AI can not do this high aspect ratio images. But if your aim was to support an artist then why would you care. And yes artists not knowing perspective seems more norm today than anything else. Looks like a photo collage. If it were AI it would most likely be better,

Comment: There's often no way to tell for sure unless there is some obvious glitch/error.  If you commissioned it, and it's not what you want, then go back to the artist/find another one.

Comment: @ kexxgem could you elaborate on that? I feel like there's good constructive criticism I can pass on to him regarding your points.

Comment: Poor perspective is not an error in art. The image probably is a collage of numerous separate images which may have good perspectives when watched separately. When one combines them together it may need a huge amount of work to warp the parts to have consistent perspectives. It's skipped here and a geometrically unreal view is generated. European art painters started gradually in 1400's aim consistent perspective. A camera with a good lens makes it automatically. But as said: Poor perspective is not an error in art, it's an error only in imaging which is expected to have exact geometry.

Comment: (continued...) Combining several images to one is difficult, because generally the parts are seen from different distances and directions, so they have all their own perspectives. You find perspective theory in basic drawing guide books for beginners. For a start read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that if it were AI generated it would be better. Or if it was AI generated then your artist isn't really ready for AI generation in first place.

**Note**: AI image generation is not as simple as it sounds. It still requires skill to get what you want and unless you started your AI image generation journey 2 years ago your no longer in the space where you can compete with the more skillful AI operators. AI is just like a tool, yes when Photoshop first came it changed a lot of things. But still there are better Photoshop operators and worse Photoshop operators. Same is true with AI.

The real challenge of AI is not in generating one cool image. But rather generating a collection of images. AI art, especially with prompting only, is a bit like ink blot drawing. You get what you get. Once you move over to generating a big collection of images your easily in territory of needing to draw/model the scaffolding for getting the art you need over and over again. Sometimes the AI is not as malleable as youd wish.

But generating the image you sent us poses a number of problems for the AI generator. So i would say its not AI generated if it was a lot of time was spend coercing tha AI to be worse than it could have been.

[image]

**Image 1**: This image was AI generated. Even though i wouldn't use this as art this demonstrates what you get with **no effort**.

The thing is AI art can easily be hard to distinguish form hastily drawn images.